# Graph Api Error Posting as page admin

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application in php using graph api.
So, I have to post messages to a Facebook page as admin. I followed this: [How to post to Facebookpage as admin via API (Php SDK)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385597/how-to-post-to-facebookpage-as-admin-via-api-php-sdk) .
It worked well a couple of time, but now it returns this error:
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request.\n  thrown in /home/redmarv/public_html/owl-test/facebook.php on line 453

But can't find where the problem is. Even with google or search other posts right there.
But I can't understand why it works a couple of time and then no.
Without changing anything.

Actually I use this code:

```
include_once "fbmain.php";

echo 'Hi ' . $uid . '<br />';

$fb_accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');

$access_token = $fb_accounts['data'][1]['access_token'];

echo 'Access Token= ' . $access_token;

$facebook->api('/page_id/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'OWL F TOOLS N TEST by: '.$uid,  'access_token'=>$access_token, 'cb'=>''));
```

The included fbmain.php does the session contro and create the $facebook object.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If a user isn't logged into your app while making graph requests, you'll get the error you describe above.

I'm assuming the code in 'fbmain.php' handles authenticating the user and returning the $uid, but if you're already not logged in before hitting this script, the code after the include 'fbmain.php' is probably running before Facebook does the login redirect.

Try including a check to make sure $uid actually contains a valid integer before using it.

```
include_once "fbmain.php";

if(is_int($uid) && $uid > 0) {
  echo 'Hi ' . $uid . '<br />';
  $fb_accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
  $access_token = $fb_accounts['data'][1]['access_token'];
  echo 'Access Token= ' . $access_token;
  $facebook->api('/page_id/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'OWL F TOOLS N TEST by: '.$uid,  'access_token'=>$access_token, 'cb'=>''));
} else {
  // wait for facebook to redirect page to loginUrl or do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For other that will have the same problem, I get rid of it.
The solution was pretty simple, if you want to post on your page wall as the page itself, you have to change this:

```
$facebook->api('/page_id/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'OWL F TOOLS N TEST by: '.$uid,  'access_token'=>$access_token, 'cb'=>''));
```

With this:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'OWL F TOOLS N TEST by: '.$uid,  'access_token'=>$access_token, 'cb'=>''));
```

This is very simple, if you are the page (using it's access_token) you want to post to your wall (so to '/me/feed').

Hoping this will help someone!