# wall post to facebook page differ than user wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

When I post a user wall post as user_id/feed it appear as left side image.It is ok.But when I target the  facebook page as page_id/feed with same code segment post display as right side image. what would be the reason for this. I want to make appear my page wall post also as left side one. Pleas help me to solve this issue.

Here I am doing this with facebook-graph api

Comment: This solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385597/how-to-post-to-facebookpage-as-admin-via-api-php-sdk