# PHP Facebook SDK Post on Page as Admin

Tags: php, facebook, post, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Graph Api - Posting to Fan Page as an Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin)

I am trying to have a form on my site where I can submit a blog post and then send that same blog post to my page on facebook.

My page is: https://www.facebook.com/foreveraloneminecraft

I want it to post it as if I was logged in and manually posted (like all the other posts on there).

I have been searching all over the place and everything I find either never actually posts something or throws an error.

This is what I got so far after searching all over:

```
<?php
include('core/init.inc.php');
require_once('libs/parser.php'); // path to Recruiting Parsers' file
$parser = new parser; //  start up Recruiting Parsers

if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['user'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'])
{
    //--- Facebook Posting ------
    require_once('libs/facebook/facebook.php');
    $appid = '286964398044671';
    $appsecret = 'myappsecret';
    $pageid = '215852885143861';
    $token = 'mytoken';

    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $appid,
      'secret' => $appsecret,
    ));

    // Get the current access token
    //$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    //Information that makes up the facebook page post
    $attachment = array(
            'access_token' => $token,
            'message' => $_POST['body'], 
            'link'    => 'http://hgs1957.hostedd.com/news.php',
            'picture' => 'http://hgs1957.hostedd.com/images/foreverAloneMCguy.png',
            'name'    => $_POST['title'],
            'description'=> 'Latest news for foreveralonemc.com.'
    );

    //Try to post to the facebook page
    try{
    $res = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/feed','POST',$attachment);

    } catch (Exception $e){

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    //Add the post to the sql database of posts
    //add_post($_POST['user'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['body']);

    //Redirect to news feed
    header('Location: news.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

I used the appsecret from the token is that I got when using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ with the permissions: publish_stream, status_update, manage_pages, publish_actions, offline_access
After trying that it seems to post to the page wall but as me not as the page or admin.

Anyone know if this is just a bug or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ok so I figured out that it was because the access token I was using was my own and not my pages. So I got my pages access token using the same explorer, and using /accounts. The only issue is that I read user access tokens expire after 60 days and therefore page access tokens.

How I would I go about getting this on the fly just in case it expired?

Answer (score 1):

You should re-login to your app again to renew and store a new access token after it is expired.
I Hope [This](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) will help you.