# Post to Facebook page as Admin

Tags: java, facebook, scribe

I didn't know Java + Facebook integration would cost an arm and a leg.
Does anyone have a sample code to post to Facebook page as admin?

I understand the OAuth process, I just need to send an OAuthRequest with my text using [scribe lib](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)  . And if possible, How to send a byte[] (a picture).

`request.addBodyParameter("status", "Testing: Updating my facebook status through Java");
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

    Response response = request.send();`

I have tried the above code from [scribe example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java) but I get `{"error":{"message":"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}`

Thanks.

Comment: This answer can perhaps be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin

Comment: Thanks @GunnarKarlsson it seems convoluted but I guess that's all I can get, will have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to generate an application token (assuming you have all the proper permissions) using the app secret and using this newly created token in your posts, etc.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for but thanks. I'm looking for sample code using scribe. I understand the theory behind it.