# Posting a Feed on a Administered Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am trying to post on a page I administered in Facebook and I use this code.

```
$fb_key['key'] = 'fb_access_token';
$access = Model_const::read_key($fb_key);
$f = new facebook\fb($cfg);
$f->setAccessToken($access['value']);

$p = 'User is not logged in';
if($f->getUser())
{
   $page_arg['access_token'] = $f->getAccessToken();
   $page_arg['fields']        = 'access_token';
   $page_info = $f->api("/$fb_id",'get',$page_arg);

   $fb  = array();
   $fb['link'] = $uri;
   $fb['message'] = Input::post('content');
   $fb['access_token'] = $page_info['access_token'];

   $p = $f->api("$fb_id/feed",'POST',$fb);
}
```

I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin) here and it appears that $page_info part is not recognized by the FB api. Reading on the documentation didn't help, though I can post using my personal account. I would like to have it on my facebook non-human page.

I was hoping if someone could provide how to do it via PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to retrieve the page access token from the admin user account
here is a link to the documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

Comment: I think OP is doing the same.

Comment: Does the paga access token expire like the user tokens?

Comment: Could you please read the whole document? The answer's already in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the permission : **manage_pages**

Add this permission with your login code.

- If you are using **getLoginUrl()**, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)
- If using the direct auth dialog url, add like this:

  $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
         . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
         . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
         . "&scope=manage_pages";

Another thing, if you want to extend page access token that **never expires**, I've explained the same in  this thread: [What are the Steps to getting a Long Lasting Token For Posting To a Facebook Fan Page from a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405)

The rest seems to be correct. Good luck.

Comment: I added it in the facebook settings.

Comment: No, not in the App Settings, that wont affect what permissions will be asked from the user. Add them to the login code using `scope` parameter