# Mention Facebook Page in Page API Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Apologies this is a duplicate post of - [Facebook Graph Api - Posting to Fan Page as an Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin?rq=1)**

The graph API states verbatim that (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed/):

> The main body of the post, otherwise called the status message. Either
>   link or message must be supplied. The message can contain mentions of
>   Facebook Pages using the following syntax:
>
> ```
>  @[page-id]
> ```
>
> For example the following message would mention the Facebook
>   Developers page inline:
>
> ```
>  Test message @[19292868552] tag
> ```

If I post to a page (for which I am an admin) with the above syntax, using a page Id for the inline link (for which I am also an admin) and using a facebook application (for which I am a developer) this doesn't appear to work. An example of my call is:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/page-id1/feed?message=Test+message+@[page-id2]+tag

In my case the tag is rendered as it appears above, i.e. no link or mention. So far I have tried:

1. Different combinations of page-id1 and page-id2.
2. HTML encoding the @, [ and ] symbols.
3. Posting as a page or as a user.
4. Using a different notation @[page-id:page-name]. This is not rendered atall, just becomes a blank space.

I must be missing something obvious if anyone is able to shed any light on this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api - Posting to Fan Page as an Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the documentation for API version 2.1, but your sample call there is unversioned and would [thus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions) be using the oldest supported version which is v1.0.

The v1.0 documentation doesn't say anything about that functionality, so it's likely only available in v2.1 or higher

The docs also say your usage of that feature needs to be approved before it can be used by the public, but i think using the correct version should get it working for you for test purposes, provided you're an admin of the App, the Page you're tagging and the Page you're updating

Comment: Thank-you for the answer but that is a copy paste error on my part. I was using the v2.1 api. I have corrected my post.

Comment: After some further searching i've also posted this on the facebook bug tracker https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1492659127667248/

Comment: Does it work when you do so as the admin of the app? for other users you need this approved before it will work

Comment: Yes I am an admin for the app.

Comment: And of both the page you're posting to and the page you're tagging? I just tested this and it worked OK for me -[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hOCK3us.png)

Comment: (my call in that example had 'message' set to: `this is a test tag of @[278905338821044] for a test` BTW)

Comment: @MarcF  Hey, I'm running to the same problem. Wondering if you'd found a fix. It would be great if you could give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for quite a while too. A clear answer was given by [Igy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21062/igy) on the [Facebook bug tracker page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1492659127667248/)...

> To clarify, for testing this functionality before submitting it for approval you must be posting as a page you admin, tagging a page you admin, and using an app you admin - otherwise the tags are not applied

This is a great answer, but I misunderstood it at first. I was trying to @[page-id] a Facebook page with my test users page. I thought since I was logged into Facebook/developers as an admin with my personal facebook account that the test users I created counted as admin users too and I would be able to @[page-id] other pages they were admins of from their page.

It seems that you can only perform this functionality with the admin account you're signed into on facebook/developers. That account must have a Facebook page they admin, you must use the page access_token and @[page-id] a facebook page they admin from your users page in order for it to work. Once I got over the fact that I can not test this in my development environment with my test users It worked perfectly!

Hope this helps anyone else that might be haveing the same problem.