# Facebook Mentions on a Facebook Page with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone had success with a mention of a FB Page via the Graph API? I'm trying to have one page mention another posting via the Graph API.

- I have permissions: "pages_read_engagement" and "pages_manage_posts".
- Have tested using FB Pages I'm the admin of with an approved app I'm admin of. Also these Pages are over 6 months old. Also using a real user (mine) and not a test user.
- Have posted with @[Page Id], @[Page Name], @[Page ID:Page Name], and @[Page Id:1:Page Name]
- Made sure in the Page setting mentions by others is allowed.
- Using Facebook SDK version 11.0

and the post always has the mentioned removed.

For example "This is great @[109904187850644]"
posts as "This is great"

The only time mentions show is when the Page mentions itself.

For reference:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-mentioning
- Related question but using version 2.1 from 7 years ago: [Mention Facebook Page in Page API Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999256/mention-facebook-page-in-page-api-post?rq=1)

Any thought on the issue? Permissions, way posting, etc?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this recently so I hope I can help you out.

To me it sounds like while you have the required permissions you are missing the actual Page Mentioning Feature. As described on the [Page Mentioning Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-mentioning) the Feature is required to @mention other Pages this is why mentioning the posting Page itself works.
To get authorization to use said feature you have to do an [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/).

Additionally you might want to read up on the differences between [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference) and [Features](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference).
From my experience there is no way to test out any functionalities requiring a Feature without doing an App Review because the Graph API will not return any useful data even in development mode while you can test out any permissions without having to do an App Review before.

Comment: The Features: "For apps in Development Mode, all Features except for Page Public Content Access and Page Public Metadata Access are active for any app user who has a Role on the app or a Role in a Business that has claimed the app." So were you never able to get a mention to work in development, but went through the review process with "Page Mention" feature and it was approved and worked in production? Maybe if you can explain more?

Comment: You're right, the issue is there is also the "feature" called Page Mentions in permissions that can't be tested in dev, except with mentioning the Page ID of the page you're posting to. Just show in your demo video a Page mentioning itself  and hopefully you'll be approved.

Comment: Exactly, I was never able to get mentioning (besides mentioning the page itself) to work before the App Review in Development or Production mode. What I ended up doing was creating a "Mock" (just the frontend with dummy data) and go through the App Review process to get the Feature approved and suddenly it worked.